# Incorrect display of the Christmas tree

Tags: java, recursion

The problem is that the stars don't form a Christmas tree, they just form a right triangle.
How to solve it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLCVb.png <--- This is what it looks like.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5cvt.png <--- This is what it should look like.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("In0103.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    int maxWidth = in.nextInt();
    int initialWidth = 1;
    int initialLevel = 1;
    int maxLevel = (maxWidth + 1) / 2;
    int freeSpace = maxLevel - 1;

    printChristmasTree(initialWidth, initialLevel, maxLevel, freeSpace, null);
}

static void printChristmasTree(int width, int level, int maxLevel, int freeSpace, PrintWriter save) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (save == null) {
        save = new PrintWriter("Out0103.txt");
    }
    if (level < maxLevel) {
        save.println(Stream.generate(() -> " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println(Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println();
        printChristmasTree(width = width + 2, ++level, maxLevel, --freeSpace, save);
    } else {
        save.println(Stream.generate(() -> " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println(Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Upvoted for christmas tree being in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. But you are printing the `freeSpace` with `save.println()` but you do not need a new line, just `save.print()`. Additionally, there is one extra `save.println()` that is also not needed:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("In0103.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    int maxWidth = in.nextInt();
    int initialWidth = 1;
    int initialLevel = 1;
    int maxLevel = (maxWidth + 1) / 2;
    int freeSpace = maxLevel - 1;

    printChristmasTree(maxWidth, initialWidth, initialLevel, maxLevel, freeSpace, null);
}

static void printChristmasTree(int maxWidth, int width, int level, int maxLevel, int freeSpace, PrintWriter save) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (save == null) {
        save = new PrintWriter("Out0103.txt");
        save.println("n =" + maxWidth + "");
    }

    if (level < maxLevel) {
        save.print(Stream.generate(() -> " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println(Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        printChristmasTree(maxWidth, width + 2, ++level, maxLevel, --freeSpace, save);
    } else {
        save.print(Stream.generate(() -> " ").limit(freeSpace).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.println(Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(width).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        save.close();
    }
}
```

And maybe you need to change the line from `int freeSpace = maxLevel - 1;` to `int freeSpace = maxLevel;`, given that it seems there is a free space in the last row of your tree.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. Consider upvoting the answer and accept it as the answer so that your question can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: I marked the answer.
But unfortunately I can't give you an upvote

Comment: That is ok! Thanks!

Comment: I have one more question. I would like the information to be displayed above the Christmas tree, how much * is the base. For example: n = 7. How to enter it in this case? Unfortunately it doesn't work like that .. save.println ("n =" + maxWidth + "");

Comment: That requires some changes. Please check my updated answer ;)